# How to handle emojis correctly in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

For example, for this sentence,

```
Hoseok yelled out Puma at the end
```

The tokenized emojis becomes "*?*?*?*?". Is this an issue for openNLP or something else?